# Presto for cassandra

Tags: cassandra, presto

I have configured Presto 0.136 on a 4 node cluster with 3 Cassandra nodes as worker nodes(with minimal config) mentioned in the presto docs.
https://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/deployment.html

I am able to start presto and use it but when I am trying to query large tables, an error pops out stating **"Query 20160202_141705_00005_xc2i3 failed: java.io.IOException: Could not get input splits"**

My cassandra is using **Murmur3Partitioner** and I used the same for presto too in catalog/cassandra.properties. I tried changing it to RandomPartitioner  but no luck.
I'm not sure why this is working with smaller tables and failing on larger ones. Can someone help me fixing this...

Thank you in advance!